# Angular 6 http response issue

Tags: angular, http, get

I have found a very strange behavior with `HttpClient` `get` request.

#### Response 1

API sends:

```
{
  payload: {
    object: {
      array: [1, 2, 3]
    }
  }
}
```

Angular receives:

```
{
  payload: {
    object: {
      array: []
    }
  }
}
```

#### Response 2

API sends:

```
{
  payload: {
    array: [
      object: {
        array: [1, 2, 3]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Angular receives:

```
{
  payload: {
    array: [
      object: {
        array: [1, 2, 3]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Do anyone met such behavior?

## Update

#### Angular code:

```
this.http
  .get(`instance/${id}`)
  .subscribe(
    response => log('get', response),
    error => log('error', error)
  );
```

#### API code:

```
async function getInstance(req, res, next) {
  const instanceId = sanitize(req.params.id);

  if (!instanceId) {
    return utils.response[400](res, {
      message: 'Missed id'
    });
  }

  if (!instanceId.match(/^[0-9a-fA-F]{24}$/)) {
    return utils.response[400](res, {
      message: 'Wrong id'
    });
  }

  const model = models['instance'];
  const query = model
    .schema
    .findById(new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(instanceId))
    .populate('subInstance')
    .select(model.select);

  try {
    const instance = await query.exec();

    if (!instance) {
      return utils.response[404](res, {
        message: 'Instance not found'
      });
    }

    return utils.response[200](res, {
      instance: instance
      // I changed the response to this and everything works:
      // instance: [instance]
    });
  } catch (err) {
    return utils.response[501](res, err);
  }
}
```

## Update 2

Response function code:

```
function sendResponse(response, status, message, payload) {
  return response
    .status(status)
    .send({
      status: status,
      message: message,
      payload: payload
    });
}

module.exports = {
  200: (res, result) => sendResponse(res, 200, 'SUCCESS', result),
  201: (res, result) => sendResponse(res, 201, 'CREATED', result),
  204: (res, result) => sendResponse(res, 201, 'UPDATED', result),
  205: (res, result) => sendResponse(res, 201, 'REMOVED', result),
  301: (res, result) => sendResponse(res, 301, 'REDIRECTED', result),
  400: (res, result) => sendResponse(res, 400, 'NOT_VALID', result),
  401: (res, result) => sendResponse(res, 401, 'NOT_AUTHENTICATED', result),
  403: (res, result) => sendResponse(res, 403, 'NOT_AUTHORIZED', result),
  404: (res, result) => sendResponse(res, 404, 'NOT_FOUND', result),
  406: (res, result) => sendResponse(res, 406, 'WRONG_TYPE', result),
  409: (res, result) => sendResponse(res, 409, 'DUPLICATE', result),
  501: (res, result) => sendResponse(res, 501, 'ELSE_SERVER', result)
};
```

## Update 3

[image]

Comment: Why you are faceing is pretty strange, I never had such behaviour. Can you add some code ?

Comment: @xrobert35 I added the code

Comment: What code is behind ? utils  of : utils.response

Comment: @xrobert35 I added the code of response function

Comment: something must be wrong but I can't see what. Can you had from the network tab of you browser the response header ? from the API.   and is  "instance" always clearly consitued when you http server answer ?

Comment: btw, you don't have any http interceptor on the angular side ?

Comment: @xrobert35 I added the screenshot. this is the main weird issue. everything is very simple. simple MEAN stack, Angular 6, Mongo + Mongoose. as you can see on the screenshot I receive the array in the network and empty array in the HttpClient response. right in the Angular HttpClient.

Comment: @xrobert35 I found the issue. my state management is not immutable and the array has been reset in one of the subscriptions to the state changes. this is why the array is empty. thank you for your help

Comment: ah cool that you have found the solution. But I haven't understand the solution :p  
you mean you subscribed more than one and one of the subscriber as clean the array ?

Answer (score -1):

It is because of the asynchronous behavior, just see whether angular is printed before the call ends.

Comment: maybe, I made a double check with the documentation https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpClient#get
and nothing

Comment: If the subscribe was called before getting the whole information juste because of the "asynchronous behavior" many application would be in trouble :)

Comment: This is what I had told, why negative marking. I really could not understand.

Comment: In angular the subscribe of http client will be called when every information will be receive, except perhaps if you are doing multi-part. It not because of the **asynchronous behavior**. How would you treat the information, if when the subscribe is called you must check that every part of your object is loaded